# Android LoaderManager and CursorAdapter with Joins and/or View (View sql)

Tags: android

I have a problem and I have not been able to solve it. I'm using CursorAdapter and LoaderManager to keep a spinner updated based on changes made to the database. The problem is that the query must use JOINS between the table "employees" and "projects", to return the projects of a certain employee. I am using ContentProviders, I have tried and if I use the URI to return information from a table only, it is updated and works perfect. But when using JOINS or a view (CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT ...), the information is loaded for the first time, but it is never updated in the correct way.

How i can use CursorAdapter and LoaderManager with JOINS between n tables?. Thanks...

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem or not, but you don't have to create a sqlite view in order to use joins.

Comment: Hi,I meant that I tried using Views and using JOINS in the contentprovider with the builder.